# Удаленное управление задачами C#

Tags: c#

Здаравствуйте, прошу вашей помощи в нацеливании на изучение конкретных тем для реализации следующей задачи (vs c#):
Существует некий web-интерфейс, через который должна быть организована возможность запуска определенных задач на удаленной машине, т.е. на ней запущен демон.

В ответе хотел бы услышать какую технологию использовать для каждой задачи, начиная с протокола обмена данными и заканчивая web интерфесом.

Comment: А что подразумевается под словом "web-интерфейс"? http, использование какого-то стандартного веб-сервера, что-то ещё?

Comment: Есть предположение, что нужно использовать IIS, используя фреймворк WCF. Канал передачи скорее всего http(s)

Answer (score 4):

Я решал подобную задачу. Получилось красиво, но это тема для полноценной статьи, а не поста на форуме. Вкратце, суть такова.

Стандартные Web-протоколы являются однонаправленными, т.е. сервер может только ответить на запрос клиента, но не инициировать событие, которое должен обработать клиент. Поэтому необходимо эмулировать такое поведение с помощью пула потоков на сервере.

Для этого на клиенте должен работать класс-наблюдатель, зависящий от интерфейса удалённой задачи. Этот интерфейс должен предоставить следующие методы

- Получить идентификатор удалённой задачи. Метод должен удалённо запустить задачу на выполнение и немедленно вернуть управление
- Получить текущий статус задачи. Метод принимает идентификатор задачи, который вернул метод, запустивший задачу, и время ожидания смены статуса задачи, а возвращает статус задачи. В моей реализации статус представлял собой легковесный класс, состоящий из процента выполнения задачи и текстового описания её состояния. Если метод вернул null, это означает, что задача завершилась.
- Отменить задачу. Метод принимает идентификатор задачи, не возвращает значения.

Клиент делает следующее. Сначала на основе данных, введённых пользователем, выбирается, какая задача должна быть запущена. На основе этого формируется нужный объект, реализующий интерфейс удалённой задачи. Сначала клиент получает идентификатор новой задачи, затем в цикле вызывает метод получения её статуса, пока он не вернёт null. У меня для взаимодействия с пользовательским интерфейсом использовался BackgroundWorker. Полученные от удалённой задачи статусы передавались методу ReportProgress. Если свойство CancellationPending, проверяемое при каждой итерации выполнения задачи, возвращало true, вызывался метод отмены задачи.

На сервере организован статический репозиторий, к которому происходят обращения клиента. Репозиторий взаимодействует с задачами через интерфейс, предоставляющий следующие члены:

- Метод запуска задачи
- Событие изменения прогресса выполнения задачи
- Событие проверки того, была ли задача отменена

При добавлении задачи в репозиторий она помещается в обёртку, которая содержит

- Автоматически сгенерированный идентификатор задачи
- AutoResetEvent для оповещения о статусе задачи
- Собственно выполняемая задача и обработчики её событий
- Текущий статус задачи
- Метод получения текущего статуса задачи
- Метод отмены задачи. Этот метод должен просто установить флаг, который проверяется в обработчике события проверки отмены задачи. Задача должна сама реализовать свою отмену в том месте, где она инициирует соответствующее событие.

При обращении к репозиторию он просто ищет в себе обёртку над задачей по запрошенному идентификатору. Если задача не найдена, в случае запроса статуса возвращает null, в случае отмены не делает ничего. Если задача найдена, то вызывается соответствующий метод обёртки над задачей.

Теперь о том, что делают ключевые методы. Метод репозитория, запускающий новую задачу, делает следующее.

- Создаёт экземпляр обёртки на основе переданной ему задачи и получает его идентификатор
- Добавляет в ThreadPool метод обёртки, запускающий задачу на выполнение, и немедленно возвращает идентификатор запущенной задачи.

Метод, запускающий задачу на выполнение, делает следующее

- Собственно запускает задачу и дожидается её завершения
- После отработки метода, запустившего задачу, удаляет обёртку над задачей из репозитория. Это желательно сделать в блоке finally. Кроме того, событие об изменении статуса задачи следует сначала инициировать, а потом закрыть.

Метод, получающий статус задачи.
 - Ждёт в течение переданного ему периода времени события об изменении статуса через AutoResetEvent.
 - Возвращает текущий статус задачи

Обработчик события изменения статуса задачи.

- Изменяет текущий статус задачи на переданный через аргумент события
- Инициирует событие AutoResetEvent о том, что статус изменился.

Ну и там ещё куча нюансов с локализацией, синхронизацией доступа к репозиторию и обработкой ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Есть ли у Вас возможность предоставить, в образовательных целях конечно, свой код программы?

Comment: К сожалению, нет. Могу порекомендовать Вам начать писать, задавая вопросы по ходу дела.

Comment: Не легче сокеты использовать?

Comment: Для чего? Для двунаправленного обмена данными? Мы не использовали сокеты, всё было через WCF. Тем более, что спрашивает человек про Web.